# jQuery and CSS Pop-up Menu Link Issue

Tags: jquery, css, menu, popup

I am in the process of developing a bottom-bar menu using CSS and jQuery. It is essentially a persistent menu that gives users quick access to different features of the site.

The bar consists of small icons (class "menu-item"), that when hovered over reveal a small contextual menu with multiple options. Options inside this div are to be clickable, but the image icon itself should also be linkable.

The html is structured as follows, where the CSS for #profile specifies a particular image for the button.

```
<div id="profile" class="menu-item">
    <div id="profile-tip" class="tip tip-submenu">
    <div class="tip-profile">--Profile Content--</div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

When the image is hovered over, the "profiles-tip" div becomes visible, which is achieved using the following javascript

```
$(".menu-item").hover(function() {
    $(this).find("div").fadeIn("fast").show(); //add 'show()'' for IE
$(this).mouseleave(function () { //hide tooltip when the mouse moves off of the element
    $(this).find("div").hide();
});
});
```

In a nutshell, I want the profiles icon to be clickable and say, link to page "profiles.php". I thought this could be easily achieved by applying the following:

```
<div id="profile" class="menu-item" onClick="window.location.href='profiles.php'">
    <div id="profile-tip" class="tip tip-submenu">
    <div class="tip-profile">--Profile Content--</div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

When this solution is applied, it causes any clicks made in the pop-up menu (ie. not on the icon itself) to also link to the same location.

Many thanks if you can decipher the above and provide some help. Willing to provide more information where necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I cooked up something for you here: http://jsfiddle.net/qstv9/

Try it :-)

Comment: hi moe, seems like your code is working excellent, I only read in his intro that he also likes the options inside the div (tooltip) to be clickable, or am i wrong?

Comment: Hi Moe, thanks for the reply.

Wouter is correct, the options inside the "div" (tooltip) should be clickable. Essentially it becomes a flyout menu. So when I hover over the first grey square (which when clicked links me to profiles) a div appears with multiple other links (that are individually clickable).

Any further help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Modified the question slightly now that I have a better understanding of what it is I'm after:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5373386/jquery-find-div-help