# jQuery find div help

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu, tooltip, contextmenu

I am currently building a menu bar that consists of icons that show a contextual submenu when hovered over. Essentially, when hovering over an icon a popup menu/tooltip appears (with more options), but the icon itself should be clickable as well.

So far, I use the following HTML construct and jQuery for each menu item:

```
<div id="profile" class="menu-item">
    <div id="profile-tip" class="tip">
        **insert profile menu options**
    </div>
</div>

<div id="search" class="menu-item">
    <div id="search-tip" class="tip">
        **insert search menu options**
    </div>
</div>
```

and

```
$(".menu-item").hover(function() {
    $(this).find("div").fadeIn("fast").show(); //add 'show()'' for IE
$(this).mouseleave(function () { //hide tooltip when the mouse moves off of the element
    $(this).find("div").hide();
});
});
```

What I wish to do is to change the HTML to look as follows (so I can apply an onClick link to the "profiles" div):

```
<div id="profile" class="menu-item" onclick="window.location = 'profile.php'"></div>
    <div id="profile-tip" class="tip">
        **insert menu options**
    </div>
```

However, I don't know how to modify the jQuery to find the matching div to display when hovered over. The associated tooltip/popup menu div will always be xxxx-tip (where xxx is the name of the parent div).

As an example, I imagine it will look something like this (keep in mind I know very little about jQuery so I'm well aware this will look stupid):

```
$(".menu-item").hover(function() {
    $.find("div").attr('id'+"-tip").fadeIn("fast").show(); //add 'show()'' for IE
$(this).mouseleave(function () { //hide tooltip when the mouse moves off of the element
    $.find("div").attr('id'+"-tip").hide();
});
});
```

To summarise: I need the jQuery modified to show the div based on the parent div's ID + the string "-tip"

Hopefully that isn't too confusing. Any help GREATLY appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I understand completely what you want, but maybe try something a little more like this:

```
$(".menu-item").hover(
    function() {
        $(this).find(".tip").fadeIn("fast").show(); //add 'show()'' for IE
    },
    function() { //hide tooltip when the mouse moves off of the element
        $(this).find(".tip").hide();
    }
);
```

**Edit**: If the tip element is not a child of the menu item div, this could work:

```
$(".menu-item").hover(
    function() {
        $('#' + this.id + '-tip').fadeIn("fast").show(); //add 'show()'' for IE
    },
    function() { //hide tooltip when the mouse moves off of the element
        $('#' + this.id + '-tip').hide();
    }
);
```

Comment: When $(this) and .find are used together, is it only searching for elements nested inside that div? 

The menu item (div="profile") and the associated tooltip (div="profile-tip") aren't nested in the html.

Comment: Yup, `find` begins in the element you specify (in this case, `this`, which is the .menu-item div. Can you update your html to reflect that they aren't nested? I'll update my answer

Comment: <div id="profile" class="menu-item" onclick="window.location = 'profile.php'"></div>
    <div id="profile-tip" class="tip">
        **insert menu options**
    </div>

Comment: I read your question again. Missed the part about exactly how you are changing your html.. sorry! but the new code I posted should work :-)

Comment: The tooltip no longer pops up when the divs are no longer nested

Comment: Look at it in action, it works even if the divs are not nested: http://jsfiddle.net/cambraca/9R9bQ/1

Comment: Excellent, thanks cambraca.

One last thing, the tooltip disappears as soon as you've moved off the icon. Previously, using the code I initially posted, I could move my mouse to the tooltip and it would stay visible. Any thoughts?

Comment: You should check my CSS solution it would handle mouse-over on both elements.

Comment: Hi Josh. Yes this can be achieved purely using CSS, but is there a way to add jQuery fadein/fadeout to this as I quite like the effect.

Comment: Almost there. Just have to figure out a way to make the hover tooltip menu stay in place when hovered over. @cambraca, in your example when moving off the icon the tooltip disappears. @Josh M., in your example I'd like to apply jQuery fadein/fadeout to the tooltip appearance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% clear on the goal here but you can get your div by ID as shown here:

```
$(".menu-item").hover(function()
{
    $(this).find(".tip").fadeIn("fast").show();
});
```

Or in CSS:

```
.menu-item .tip
{
    display: none;
}

.menu-item .tip:hover,
.menu-item:hover .tip
{
    display: auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Apologies for my almost incoherent first post.

The jQuery needs to be generic. So when the div "profiles" is hovered over, it finds the div "profiles-tip" and makes it visible. When the div "search" is hovered over, it finds the div "search-tip" and make it visible.

Comment: Right, so instead of referencing the div by ID, reference its class.

Comment: CSS is much easier and cleaner for this - check my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of finding the name of the div in the PARENT of the thing you're hovered over, use jQuery to find the tooltip that is a CHILD of the thing you're hovered over...search down the DOM, instead of UP.

[Use jQuery's $(this) operator](http://remysharp.com/2007/04/12/jquerys-this-demystified/)...

```
$('.menu-item').hover(function(){
     $(this).find('.tip).fadeIn();


},
function() {
    $(this).find('.tip).fadeOut();
});
```